# How to find the location (row/column) of the minimum/maximum value of a data frame or a matrix (R question)

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

I want to find the location of the minimum or maximum value of a data frame or a matrix.

For example, let me use the example of a matrix of minimum (and let's not consider the presence of the same values, for now):

```
B<-matrix(c(1.5,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,4,6,8,10),nrow=3,ncol=5)
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   1.5    4    4    1    6
[2,]    2    5    3    2    8
[3,]    3    5    2    4   10
```

What I want the output is:

row.number = 1

column.number = 4

I tried which.min or which.max. It only returns the "total" location as if the input is a vector (it will return the single number 4)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `which.min` and friends does not support this directly, `which(..., arr.ind=TRUE)` does:

```r
which(B == min(B), arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   4
```

**Very important** side note: there are two notes when doing this:

1. This does not report the existence of ties; and
2. This assumes that equality of floating-point will work, which is prone to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518) and [R FAQ 7.31](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272). So while this probably works most of the time, it is *feasible* that it will not always work. In the case when it doesn't work, it will return a 0-row `matrix`. One mitigating step would be to introduce a tolerance, such as

   ```r
   which(abs(B - min(B)) < 1e-9, arr.ind=TRUE)
   #      row col
   # [1,]   1   4
   ```

   where `1e-9` is deliberately small, but "small" is relative to the range of expected values in the matrix.

### Faster Alternative

Honestly, `which.max` gives you enough information, given you know the dimensions of the matrix.

```r
m <- which.min(B)
c( (m-1) %% nrow(B) + 1, (m-1) %/% nrow(B) + 1 )
# [1] 1 4
```

For background, a `matrix` in R is just a vector, ordered in columns.

```R
matrix(1:15, nrow=3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10   13
# [2,]    2    5    8   11   14
# [3,]    3    6    9   12   15
```

So we can use the modulus `%%` and integer-division (floor) `%/%` to determine to row and column number, respectively:

```r
(1:15-1) %% 3 + 1
#  [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
(1:15-1) %/% 3 + 1
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

And it turns out that this last method is much faster (not too surprising, considering the hard part is done in C):

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = which(B == min(B), arr.ind=TRUE),             # first answer, imperfect
  b = which(abs(B - min(B)) < 1e-9, arr.ind=TRUE),  # second, technically more correct
  c = {                                             # third, still correct, faster
    m <- which.min(B)
    c( (m-1) %% nrow(B) + 1, (m-1) %/% nrow(B) + 1 )
  }, times=10000)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr min  lq     mean median   uq   max neval
#     a 8.4 9.0 10.27770    9.5 10.4  93.5 10000
#     b 9.0 9.6 10.94061   10.3 11.1 158.4 10000
#     c 3.3 4.0  4.48250    4.2  4.7  38.7 10000
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: CharlotteDeng, I thought about it a moment longer and added what I think it is a very important note. I believe that many data-manglers do not appreciate the nuances of floating-point equality in programming languages (including but not exclusively R), so I *do* suggest that you take at least 3 minutes to read from those two links. In general R tries to do the "right-enough" thing, but it will fail when you need it the most (or forget about this comment).

Comment: one could let `which.min()` handle the nuance of numerical equality, and use `idx <- which.min(B)` and then recover row and column index `c(row(B)[idx], col(B)[idx])`

Comment: @MartinMorgan, I wasn't as certain until I looked at the source, and you are right: since it only does tests of `<` (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e85c4a3b16e17418199348246563746df3c58afe/src/main/summary.c#L1052), it is safe from the woes of floating-point equality.